# Evaluating the value of |$f'(x)$|

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inequality

Let $f \in C^2[0,2]$ and $|f(x)| \le 1, |f''(x)|\le1$ for all $x \in[0,1]$

Prove that $|f'(x)|\le2 $ for all $x \in [0,2]$

---

I tried Taylor expansion to evaluate $|f'(x)|$, but it seems to work only when $x\in[0,1]$. I'm confused when it comes to $x \in [1,2]$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117991/42969

Comment: the final $[0,2]$ must be a typo - the problem is clearly wrong as stated

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right. I found a counterexample.