# Is the n-th derivative operator closed, on its natural domain, with the sup norm?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

> Consider the Banach space $X:=C([0, 1])$ with the usual sup norm 
>   $$
> \|f\|:=\sup_{x\in[0, 1]} |f(x)|.$$ 
>   For $k\ge 1$, let $D(T)=C^k([0, 1])$ and define a linear operator 
>   $$
> T\colon D(T)\to X, \qquad Tf:= f^{(k)}.$$
>   Is $T$ *closed*, meaning that its graph $\{(f, Tf)\ :\ f\in D(T)\}$ is a closed subset of $X\times X$?

The answer is affirmative for $k=1$ and the proof is a standard exercise; assuming that $f_n \to f$ and $Tf_n=f'_n \to g$, we note that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_0^x f_n'(y)\, dy, $$ 
so passing to the limit, as we may because of uniform convergence,
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x g(y)\, dy, $$
which implies that $f\in C^1([0, 1])$ and $f'=g$, that is, $Tf=g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Iterative application of your proof of course shows that $C^{k}([0,1])$ with the norm $\|f\|=\sum_{l=0}^k \|f^{(l)}\|_\infty$ is complete, so it suffices to prove that this norm is equivalent to $\|f\|_\infty+\|f^{(k)}\|_\infty$. Let's assume $k=2$ for the sake of simplicity.

Let $x\in [0,1]$ such that $|f'|$ attains its maximum in $x$. By the mean value theorem,
$$
f(y)=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+\frac 1 2f''(a)(y-x)^2
$$
for some $a\in [0,1]$. Thus
$$
\|f'\|_\infty\leq \inf_{y\in[0,1]}\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}+\frac 1 2\|f''\|_\infty|y-x|\leq 4\|f\|_\infty+\frac 1 2\|f''\|_\infty.
$$
(Ignore all the constants, they are probably not optimal and possibly wrong.)